# translating a Ruby query to javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby

**updated question**

I want to highlight weeks of the datepicker that have the sum of hours below 40. To do this i have to look at the records table for the last 3 weeks and with the current user. Ive written some code below that i know isnt right but hopefully you can get the jist. Ive been told to not put this in js but i dont know how id do this any other way considering i have to come back to js in order to set the colour of the highlight on the datepicker?

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
        record = Record.sum(:hours,:where => :week => date && :user_id => current_user.id )
    }
```

Comment: You can't simply translate this to JavaScript, as you don't have the `Record` class available there, for example. Perhaps you could try rephrasing your question?

Comment: Perhaps expose the report you want as an action, and get the data via Ajax?

Comment: ok updated.. hope thats alittle better?

Comment: I'd urge you to look into what Dave has suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, not really an elegant solution, but I would do as follows ( no need for an extra ajax call here ):

in your controller/action:

..

```
@record = Record.sum(:hours,:where => :week => date && :user_id => current_user.id ).to_json
```

..

then create a hidden div in your view:

```
<div class='hidden' id='records'>
   <%= @record %>
</div>
```

and in your js:

```
record = $.parseJSON( $('#records').text() );
```

..

and you'll have your ruby object/objects translated into js